# Batch write text in txt file at line 17

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a program that write/replaces text at line 17 in a .txt file.
I tried out this, but its only working for two lines

```
@Echo off
Echo hello >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> test.txt
```

Its outcome is:

```
">> was unexpected at this time."
```

But this work just fine:

```
@Echo off
Echo hello >> test.txt
```

Comment: Read http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: Do you need to insert a new line of text at line 17, or do you need to replace the existing line at line 17? `>>` is used only for adding lines.

Comment: The inventiveness of people never ceases to amaze me! I can't imagine how you got it in your head that the number of `>` characters indicates what line is being written.

Comment: I, need to replace the line ;)
I thought it was a bit weird with 17 ">" :P
And thanks JosefZ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" test.txt') do (
   if %%a neq 17 (
      echo(%%b
   ) else (
      echo The new line 17
   )
)) > output.txt
move /Y output.txt test.txt
```

This solution eliminate the colons that may appear at beginning of the line. This problem may be fixed, if needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

For x = 1 to 16
    OutP.WriteLine Inp.Readline
Loop
Inp.Readline
OutP.WriteLine wscript.Arguments(0)
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    OutP.WriteLine Inp.Readline
Loop
```

Name it something.vbs

to use

```
cscript //nologo something.vbs "Line 17 text" < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, the cmd just outputs "loop" without "do". Then when I'm opening the text file it's blank :/

Comment: The question asked about doing this from a batch file, not from VBScript.

Comment: I choose the best solution to the problem. It is misusing batch to do things like this. Plus in normal batch you can't do it simply but have to turn on alternative modes. Go back to msnews 95 groups.